# Can I use Hibernate Validator 5 without EL?

Tags: java, groovy, hibernate-validator

Upgrading to the latest Hibernate Validator in my Java desktop application causes `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/PropertyNotFoundException`.  It turns out that by default, Hibernate Validator now depends on EL.

Can it be configured to not use EL?  I'm okay with the previos version messaging format (without EL). I'm already using Groovy in my project.  I believe including dependencies to EL in my current project is redundant since both serve the same purpose as scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, you can't use Hibernate Validator 5 without an EL implementation.

What you can do is to plug in a custom `MessageInterpolator` which doesn't make use of the expression language. There is also a feature request in our JIRA ([HV-853](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-853)) to add such a message interpolator to Hibernate Validator. Maybe you would be interested in helping out with this?

Comment: I guess I can create a custom `MessageInterpolator` to use Groovy in my project. I would really like to help but I don't think I have the resources to contribute a solution for HV-853 that will work on any scripting engines.